# Find a sequence of R-integrable functions whose pointwise limit is R-integrable but the limit of $\int (f_n)$ does not equal to $\int f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

There exists a sequence of Riemann integrable functions
$(fn)$ on $[0, 1]$ whose pointwise limit $f$ is still Riemann integrable, but for
which
$$\begin{equation} \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \ne \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx  \end{equation}$$

Answer (score 3):

Take a sliding bump function $f_n(x)=2n$ for $x\in\left[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}\right]$ and zero elsewhere. Then $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ pointwise. On the other hand $1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\neq \int_0^1f(x)dx=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But can we prove that $f_n$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @bestannie: of course it's Riemann integrable, it's basically a step function.